# Instantiation of template

Tags: c++, templates

If I have the following code:

```
template <typename T = int>
struct mystruct {
  using doublestruct = mystruct<double>;
}

mystruct<>::doublestruct obj;
```

Does this instantiate the `mystruct<int>` template at all? Or only the `mystruct<double>` is instantiated?

Comment: You didn't use the "T" type in the template. What are you trying to achieve with such template?

Comment: @MykhayloKopytonenko: It's a contrived example. A very good testcase, actually. He's asking whether a template is instantiated when it's named only to name a [non-dependent] member type declared within it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it will have to instantiate `mystruct<int>` in order to access its members and determine the meaning of `doublestruct`. You could test this with a `static_assert`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T = int>
struct mystruct {
  static_assert(!std::is_same<T,int>::value, "");
  using doublestruct = mystruct<double>;
};

mystruct<>::doublestruct obj;     // assertion fails for T==int
mystruct<char>::doublestruct obj; // OK, not instantiated for int
```

Comment: mebe use something other than `double` for this demonstration; kinda confusing

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: OK, I guess.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it must be instantiated; `doublestruct` is a member of the instantiation so, if you do not have an instantiation, you do not have a `doublestruct`.

> `[C++11: 14.7.1]:` Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program. *[..]*

In particular, consider the potential effect of specialisations of `mystruct` that may not contain a member `doublestruct`, or may contain one that is not a type.